# laptop keyboard turns off after selecting OS in grub

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard

The keyboard of my laptop turns off as soon as I select an OS from the grub menu and boot into it. It works before that and it stops working irrespective of the OS selected (all Linuxes however). I can connect a USB keyboard and it works just fine. Dropping into text mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> does not make the keyboard turn on again. btw, I say "turn off" and "turn on", because even the backlight of the keyboard goes dark.

This is the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 99)
03:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8620 (rev 01)
```

I don't see a keyboard listed, but I don't know what the output was when the keyboard did work.

Any other commands I can run to gather information?

Btw, I did not manually install any new programs or edit any configs since they keyboard worked last time and now.

edit:

The pointer stick that is part of they keyboard (thinkpad) does work however.

Answer (score 0):

Booting into recovery mode and running "fix broken packages" fixed it for all installed distros. But why I don't understand.